# Differences between glmmadaptive Vs lme4 and glmmTMB in ICC measurement

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, intraclass-correlation, glmmtmb, glmmadaptive

This is my first question, so please be kind...

I am currently modelling a GLMM with a binary outcome with many (500+) clusters but cluster size of 2 (by design - there can be no more than 2 per cluster). I am specifically interested in the ICC and the contribution of the grouping variable to the dichotomous outcome - I am including other (fixed effects).

However, I seem to get very different answers from the GLMMAdaptive package compared to the results from glmmTMB and lme4 packages (which are very similar). 
I'm now stuck on what would be the most appropriate package to choose/what I should report. I was hoping for some advice regarding this issue.

I have simulated on my own data but here is example code and table below based on varying the degree of concordance within the paired data:

```
# Simulate outcome, random numbers and groups
set.seed(283)
Out_1 <- rbinom(500, 1, 0.4)
Random <- rnorm(1:length(Out_1))
ID <- seq(1,length(Out_1), 1)
trial_db <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, Out_1, Random))

# Make outcome logical so I can set 'paired' outcome to same or opposite
trial_db$Out_1log <- trial_db$Out_1 == 1

result <-  list()
i <- 0.05
rindex <- 0
results <- repeat {

  trial_db$Out_2 <- with(trial_db, ifelse(Random <= unname(quantile(trial_db$Random, i)), as.numeric(Out_1log), as.numeric(!Out_1log)))

  # Make in to long format Random effects

  one_db <- trial_db %>% dplyr::select(ID, Out_1) %>% rename(OUT = Out_1)
  two_db <- trial_db %>% dplyr::select(ID, Out_2) %>% rename(OUT = Out_2)
  long_db <- rbind(one_db, two_db) %>% arrange(ID)
  long_db$ID <- as.factor(as.character(long_db$ID))

  mod.adp <- GLMMadaptive::mixed_model(fixed = OUT ~ 1, random = ~ 1 | ID, data = long_db, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
  mod.tmb <- glmmTMB::glmmTMB(OUT ~ (1|ID), data = long_db, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
  mod.lme <- lme4::glmer(OUT ~ (1|ID), data = long_db, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
  ADAP <- round(icc(mod.adp)[[1]], 3)
  TMB <- round(icc(mod.tmb)[[1]], 3)
  LME4 <- round(icc(mod.lme)[[1]], 3)

  estimates <- cbind(i, ADAP, TMB, LME4)
  rindex <- rindex + 1
  result[[rindex]] <- estimates

  i <- i + 0.05

  if(i == 0.95) {
    break
  }
}

table <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, result)
```

Here is the output from code above:

```
      i  ADAP   TMB  LME4
1  0.05 0.000    NA    NA
2  0.10 0.000    NA    NA
3  0.15 0.000    NA    NA
4  0.20 0.001    NA    NA
5  0.25 0.001    NA    NA
6  0.30 0.001    NA    NA
7  0.35 0.003    NA    NA
8  0.40 0.002    NA    NA
9  0.45 0.003    NA    NA
10 0.50 0.017    NA    NA
11 0.55 0.126 0.066 0.066
12 0.60 0.267 0.154 0.154
13 0.65 0.412 0.274 0.274
14 0.70 0.551 0.421 0.420
15 0.75 0.678 0.570 0.570
16 0.80 0.789 0.700 0.700
17 0.85 0.877 0.806 0.805
18 0.90 0.936 0.897 0.897
19 0.95 0.959 0.995 0.995
```

Comment: GLMMadaptive uses Adaptive Gaussian Quadrature as approximation, while lme4 or glmmTMB use - I think - la place approximation. That's why results differ.

Comment: That said, you might get more similar results when you increase the value for the `nAGQ` argument in `glmer()`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I figured it was something to do with the way the models are fit. My issue is which to report...is there any guidance on this? The author of the Adaptive package suggests AGQ is the 'gold standard' but the reasoning is beyond me.

Thanks

Comment: Check this link: https://macsphere.mcmaster.ca/handle/11375/17272